# Explicit construction for unitary extensions of completely positive and trace preserving (CPTP) maps?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, research-level, quantum-information

Given a completely positive and trace preserving map $\Phi : \textrm{L}(\mathcal{H})\to\textrm{L}(\mathcal{G})$, it is clear by the Kraus representation theorem that there exist $A_k \in \text{L}(\mathcal{H}, \mathcal{G})$ such that $\Phi(\rho) = \sum_k A_k \rho A_k^\dagger$ for all density operators $\rho$ on $\mathcal{H}$. (I'll consider the special case $\mathcal{H} = \mathcal{G}$ for simplicity.)

If we use then the system+environment model to express this action as $\Phi(\rho)=\text{Tr}_{\mathcal{H}_E} (Y\rho Y^\dagger)$ for an isometry $Y$ from $\mathcal{H}$ to $\mathcal{H}\otimes\mathcal{H}_E$, where $\mathcal{H}_E$ is an ancilla modelling the environment, what is an explicit construction for a unitary $U$ that has the same action on inputs of the form $\rho\otimes\left|0\right>\left<0\right|_E$? That is, how can I construct an explicit dilation of the map to a unitary acting on a larger space? I understand that this is possible by Steinspring's dilation theorem, but actually constructing an explicit form for the dialated unitary I have had much less success with.

Comment: There used to be Joe Fitzsimmons' answer here, what happened?

Comment: @Marcin: I deleted it because there was an error in the proof.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The isometry $Y:\mathcal H\rightarrow \mathcal H_E \otimes \mathcal H$ is
$$
Y=\left(\begin{array}{c} A_1 \\ \vdots \\ A_K
\end{array}\right)
 = \sum_k |k\rangle \otimes A_k\ .
$$
Clearly, 
$$
\mathrm{tr}_E(Y\rho Y^\dagger) = \sum_{kl} \mathrm{tr}(|k\rangle\langle l|) A_k\rho A_l^\dagger   =
\sum_k A_k \rho A_k^\dagger \ ,
$$
as desired.
Moreover, $Y$ is an isometry, $Y^\dagger Y=I$, i.e., its columns are orthonormal, which follows from the condition $\sum_k A_k^\dagger A_k=I$ (i.e., the map is trace preserving).

Now if you want to obtain a unitary which acts on $|0\rangle\langle 0|\otimes \rho$ the same way $Y$ acts on $\rho$, you have to extend the matrix $Y$ to a unitary by adding orthogonal column vectors. For instance, you can pick linearly independent vectors from your favorite basis and orthonormalize. (Clearly, $U$ is highly non-unique, as its action on environment states other than $|0\rangle$ is not well defined.)

Answer (score 4):

This is just to complement the other answer by providing a more explicit derivation.

We have a map $\Phi(\rho)=\sum_k A_k \rho A_k^\dagger$ and we want to find a unitary $\mathcal U$, acting on a bigger system+environment space, such that:
$$\newcommand{\tr}{\operatorname{tr}}
\tr_E\big(\mathcal U(\rho\otimes|0\rangle\!\langle0|)\mathcal U^\dagger\big) = \Phi(\rho), \tag1
$$
where $|0\rangle$ is some (pure) state of the environment.

To see the connection between $\mathcal U$ and the Kraus operators of $\Phi$, let us decompose it as
$$\mathcal U=
\sum_{ijkl} u_{ij,k\ell} |i\rangle\!\langle k|\otimes |j\rangle\!\langle \ell| \equiv
\sum_{ijkl} u_{ij,k\ell} |i,j\rangle\!\langle k,\ell|,
$$
where $i, j$ refer to the system and $k, l$ to the environment degrees of freedom.
The action of $\mathcal U$ over $\rho\otimes|0_E\rangle\!\langle0_E|$ gives
$$\begin{gathered}
\mathcal U(\rho\otimes|0_E\rangle\!\langle0_E|) \mathcal U^\dagger
= u_{ij,kl}u^*_{mn,pq}
  |ij\rangle\!\langle mn| \,\,
  \langle k\ell|(\rho\otimes|0\rangle\!\langle0|) |pq\rangle\\
  = u_{ij,k0}u^*_{mn,p0} \rho_{kp} \,\, |ij\rangle\!\langle mn|,
\end{gathered}$$
where every index is assumed to be implicitly summed over.
Taking the trace over the environment now gives:
\begin{aligned}
\tr_E\Big[\mathcal U(\rho\otimes|0_E\rangle\!\langle0_E|) \mathcal U^\dagger \Big]
= \sum_{ijkmp}
u_{ij,k0}u^*_{mj,p0} \rho_{kp} |i\rangle\!\langle m|
= \sum_j A^j \rho\, (A^j)^\dagger,
\end{aligned}
where we defined the linear operators $A^j$ with elements $(A^j)_{ik}\equiv u_{ij,k0}$.
The above tells us that the action of an arbitrary unitary evolution $\mathcal U$ on the enlarged space, when looking only at the effective evolution over the reduced state, amounts to a mapping of the form
$\rho\mapsto \sum_j A^j\rho (A^j)^\dagger$, as we expected.

In other words, **(1)** is verified with any $\mathcal U$ satisfying
$(\mathcal U)_{ik,j0}=A^k_{ij}$, or, equivalently,
$$(I\otimes \langle k\rvert)\mathcal U(I\otimes\lvert 0\rangle) = A^k.$$

An intuitive way to understand the above constraint is by considering the environment as the *first* space (so the opposite of the way we have written above). Note that this doesn't change anything of relevance, it is just a different way to represent the same things.
However, when the environment is the first space, we can think of $\mathcal U$ as composed of a number of blocks (submatrices), each one characterizing the action of $\mathcal U$ on the system when looking at a specific input-output combination over the environment.

The above reasoning can be pictured as following:

[image]

where in this example the environment has dimension 3.

With the above picture in mind, the condition $\sum_k A^{k\dagger}A^k=\mathbb 1$ is also straightforwardly understood: it is equivalent to asking the columns of $\mathcal U$ corresponding to the input state of the environment (that is, the columns in the middle block in the image above) to be a set of orthonormal vectors.